# Gram Schmidt process - Maple Implementation

Tags: process, maple

I'm looking for full code of Gram-Schmidt process in Maple. I've found one in MatLab but I can't "translate" it. I know that there is the GramSchmidt method in Maples library, but I need to have full code.
Does anyone know how to write it? Maybe someone has done it yet.

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Answer (score 1):

How about starting off with the code of Maple's own Library implementations, to see what you can make of them? They are not very complicated.

For example, for a set (or list) of Vectors (capitalized V - `Vector`),

```
restart:
interface(verboseproc=3):
print(LinearAlgebra:-GramSchmidt);
```

and for a set (or list) of lists or now deprecated vectors (lowercase v - `vector`),

```
restart:
interface(verboseproc=3):
print(linalg[GramSchmidt]);
```